# how to release uiview added as subview in scrollview?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, subview

i have added a UIViewController's view and a button to scrollview as subview...now how do i release all instance of  UIViewController's...here is an attached image[image]

in the view every uiview has a button over it for further navigation....

now i want to release uiview's and remove buttons from the scrollview ...here is my method to add subviews
    -(void)AddOneButton:(NSInteger)myButtonTag {
    lastButtonNumber = lastButtonNumber + 1;

```
if ((lastButtonNumber == 1) || ((lastButtonNumber%2) == 1)) {
btnLeft = 8;}
else if ((lastButtonNumber == 2) || ((lastButtonNumber%2) == 0)) {
btnLeft = 162;
}

 CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(btnLeft, btnTop, 150, 150);
CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(btnLeft, btnTop, 150, 150);
UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
Button.frame = frame1;
Button.tag = myButtonTag;
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[Button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"WaitScreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"WaitScreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
if(categoryType==1)
{
    MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj = [[MultiChoiceThumbViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:myButtonTag+1];
    MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj.view.frame=frame2;
    MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj.lblCounter.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d",myButtonTag+1,flashCardsId.count];
    MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj.lblQuestion.text=[flashCardText objectAtIndex:myButtonTag];
    [myScrollView addSubview:MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj.view];       
}
[myScrollView addSubview:Button];
 }
```

with this code subviews count of scrollview is=96.

i have used this method in dealloc to remove subviews but it is not releasing UIvicontroller's

```
     for(UIView *subview in [myScrollView subviews])
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"Subviews Count=%d",myScrollView.subviews.count);
    }
```

how do i release uiviewcontroller's???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created your `UIViewController`s you never released your own ownership of it, so until you release it yourself, it will never go away.  The problem is that nothing else owns the `UIViewController`s, so if you used `autorelease`, they would be deallocated right away.

My solution would be to create an `NSMutableArray` and add them to the array before calling release on them.  Then, when you want to release all of your `UIViewController`s, remove them from the array.  `NSMutableArray` retains ownership of objects you add to it and releases ownership upon removal or deallocation.  Something like this:

```
-(id) init {
    subViewControllers = [NSMutableArray new];
}
...
-(void)AddOneButton:(NSInteger)myButtonTag {
    ...
    if(categoryType==1) {
        MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj = [[MultiChoiceThumbViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:myButtonTag+1];
        MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj.view.frame=frame2;
        MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj.lblCounter.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %d",myButtonTag+1,flashCardsId.count];
        MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj.lblQuestion.text=[flashCardText objectAtIndex:myButtonTag];
        [myScrollView addSubview:MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj.view];
        [subViewControllers addObjet:MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj];
        [MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj release];
    }
    [myScrollView addSubview:Button];
}
...
- (void) removeSuperviews {
    for(UIView *subview in [myScrollView subviews]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            NSLog(@"Subviews Count=%d",myScrollView.subviews.count);
    }
    [subViewControllers removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: thanks so much it worked...could you please explain this in more detailed manner

Comment: you missed this  [MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj release];
line after this line [subViewControllers addObjet:MultiChoiceThumbViewControllerobj];